# Altair: How to draw choropleth using projection system not listed in Altair.chart.project type?

Tags: gis, geopandas, altair, vega

new to Altair and Geopandas, was trying to create a choropleth in Jupyter based on a shapefile until I encountered a problem:

Seems like altair projection is inherited from Vega based on this document:
https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Projection.html

And the Vega page [https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/] says I can "register all extended projections from d3-geo-projection with Vega".

My questions are:

1. Does Altair also support the extended projections since it basically inherited the grammar from Vega?
2. If so, how to import the extended projection in Jupyter Notebook?
3. I actually need to use a state specific projection, California Albers (EPSG:3310), and it couldn't be found in d3-geo-projection, what should I do to make Altair "understand" this additional projection? Can I import my own projection?

Thanks a lot if you could help me with those questions : )